# Does PutAndUnlock on DataCache without supplying tags remove existing tags for that item?

Tags: appfabric, appfabric-cache

My scenario is that I have an item in the cache with several existing tags. I want to update the item using the [PutAndUnlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff424576.aspx) method. Do I need to first retrieve any existing tags and pass them to the [PutAndUnlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff424576.aspx) method to preserve them?

Related to that, adding new tags, would I have to get the existing tags and append any new ones before passing them to the [PutAndUnlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff424576.aspx) method?

Answer (score 0):

The switch (operationInfo.OperationType) case MDHOperationType.PUT_AND_UNLOCK in Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.MultiDirectoryHashtable.PreProcess(AMDHObjectNode oldObjectNode, ref AMDHObjectNode newObjectNode, ref MDHOperationInfo operationInfo) is where the MDHOperationInfo determines whether the existing item is null (or throws), or if it should do the put.
PreProcess was called by 
MultiDirectoryHashtable.PutNodeInSlot(ref MDHOperationInfo operationInfo, MDHDirectoryNode dir, int slotIndex).
The return from PreProcess is true, so it should end up calling dir.PutNodeInSlot(slotIndex, newObjectNode), which would have what I believe is the final answer.

As far as I can tell, it just does a simple assignment into the MDHNode slot, without doing any comparison of the Tags. It assigns a new Version using   operationInfo.AssignNewInternalCacheItemVersion(), but I can't see where it ever does anything with the Tags.

If you look at usages for the NewCacheItem property on Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.MDHOperationInfo, they don't seem to be touching the Tags.